# Регионы. Убрать всплывающую подсказку

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Вопрос касается модуля "Регионы" (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/regions-docpage/). Указано, что поле "hintContent" содержит в себе содержимое всплывающей подсказки, которая будет появляться при наведении курсора на регион. По умолчанию отображается его название.

Прошу подсказать, как убрать отображение всплывающих hint'ов при наведении на регион.

Пытался сделать regionsState.properties.set({'hintContent': ''}); (код ниже)

```js
ymaps.borders.load('001', {
  lang: 'ru',
  quality: 2
}).then(function(geojson) {
  var regionsState = ymaps.geoQuery(geojson);
});
regionsState.search('properties.iso3166 != "RU"').setOptions({
  'fillColor': 'rgba(153,153,153,0.5)',
});
regionsState.search('properties.iso3166 = "RU"').setOptions({
  'fillOpacity': '0',
});
regionsState.properties.set({'hintContent': ''});
regionsState.addToMap(map);
});
```

Однако, как понимаю, возникает ошибка, т.к. всплывающая подсказка не пропадает, да ещё и заливка пропадает.

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете .setOptions() для того, чтобы добавить опции, но для того, чтобы изменить properties вы пытаетесь использовать поле properties. Это нелогично https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult-docpage/ =)

```
regionsState.setProperties({'hintContent': ''});
```

Но если вы просто хотите выключить хинты, то правильней будет так:

```
regionsState.setOptions({hasHint: false});
```